# MySQL script to convert DateTime.Ticks values to SQL Date

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, datetime

I have an old MySQL database where I stored dates as C# [DateTime.Ticks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks(v=vs.110).aspx).

Now I want to convert that old database to a new structure for a PHP app that has needs a datefield. How do I convert DateTime.Ticks to MySQL dates?

I am looking for something in the following format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss`:

```
SELECT someconversion(olddate) as newDate FROM table;
```

Thank you so much in advance

Answer (score 5):

Dotnet Ticks are stored in 64-bit integers in units of 100ns (ten million per second)  since an epoch of 0001-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.

MySQL [Days (as used in `FROM_DAYS()`)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-days) count elapsed days from 0000-01-01.

For example `2016-01-09 00:00:00` in Ticks is `635879124000000000` or, for readability

```
  635 879 124 000 000 000
```

So, presumably your `oldate` column datatype is `BIGINT` or `DOUBLE` in MySQL. Either that, or it's a text string.

The thing to know is that the UNIX Epoch, `1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC`, has this Ticks value: `621355968000000000`. This is the ultimate magic number.

At any rate, here's how to convert Ticks within MySQL. We'll convert to UNIX timestamps, then to `DATETIME` columns.

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME((yourcolumn/10000000.0) - (62135596800.0))
```

But, here's the thing. The output of this `FROM_UNIXTIME()` gets converted implicitly to your local time.  You may want to preserve the UTC times when you store this data.

There are two ways to do that.  One is to use the `TIMESTAMP` datatype to store these converted times. The other is to set your MySQL session timestamp to 'UTC' before you do this conversion operation, like this:

```
  SET time_zone = 'UTC';
```

Here is another way to do the same thing, but one that doesn't depend on using Unix timestamps. (Those timestamps are only valid from 1970 to 2038.)  It depends on converting ticks to days, then on converting the remainder to seconds. It converts ticks directly to a DATETIME data type.

```
select FROM_DAYS(365+(yourcolumn / 864000000000))
   + INTERVAL (yourcolumn % 864000000000) / 10000000 SECOND
```

The constant 864000000000 (864 000 000 000) is the number of ticks in a day.

Breaking this down:

1. `yourcolumn / 864000000000` is the number of days since 0001-01-01
2. `FROM_DAYS(365+(yourcolumn / 864000000000))` is the date.
3. `(yourcolumn % 864000000000) / 10000000` is the remainder of the division in step 1, in seconds.
4. `FROM_DAYS(date) + INTERVAL seconds SECOND` gets the full timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

is this what you want?

```
select DATE_FORMAT([yourcolumn],'%Y-%M-%D %H:%m:%s') from [yourtable];
```

Here's the link for variant date format [Date format options](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp)

Answer (score -1):

This was a pain for me, but what I did was to store datetime.ticks in DB as Bigint then...
`Datetime MyDateTimeVar = new datetime(Convert.toint64(DB.ticks));` //This gets the datetime from ticks!

Comment: I believe the goal was to do a transformation in the DB using SQL so that the data is stored as a `DATETIME` or a `TIMESTAMP`.